# How to avoid repetition of setIdGenerator for all the classes in c# mongodb?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-core

```
public static void RegisterMappings()
        {
            BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Job>(map =>
            {
                map.AutoMap();
                map.IdMemberMap.SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance);
            });

            BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<JobRun>(map =>
            {
                map.AutoMap();
                map.IdMemberMap.SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance);
            });
        }
```

In all the classes in my project, I have Id property. I have to set idgenerator for all the classes. How to avoid the repitition of code?

Answer (score 1):

If you define for example interface `ISetIdGenerator` for all classes you need to register it, you could do following:

```
var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ExportedTypes
           .Where(x=>x.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ISetIdGenerator)));

foreach (var type in types)
{
    var classMap = new BsonClassMap(type);
    classMap.AutoMap();
    classMap.IdMemberMap.SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance);
    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap(classMap);
}
```

Sure, you could avoid this interface and register mapper for all classes in solution, but i think it's a little bit overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `IClassMapConvention` and register that.

```
public class IdGeneratorClassMapConvention : ConventionBase, IClassMapConvention
{
    public void Apply(BsonClassMap classMap)
    {
            map.AutoMap();
            map.IdMemberMap.SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance);
    }
}
```

and register it

```
        ConventionRegistry.Register("IdGeneratorConvention", new ConventionPack
        {
            new IdGeneratorClassMapConvention()
        }, t => !t.GetTypeInfo().IsEnum);
```

This will apply it to all non-enum types. You still need to call `BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<T>()` iirc. The second parameter `t => !t.GetTypeInfo().IsEnum` is a filter to limit the types.