# String id's in the mongodb c# driver using the fluent api

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm having a problem with a simple test program in c# (.net 6, vstudio 2022) using the mongodb driver (version 2.14.1).

I am attempting to configure the id field of a class using the api when registering ClassMaps (I don't want my classes to "know" about mongodb stuff). The code below using BsonId attribute works, and I get a new id for each record inserted into the collection "Values". However, if I remove the BsonId attribute in the `ValueBase` class, and uncomment the line `cm.IdMemberMap.SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance);` I instead get a complaint about duplicate keys (null) and the program crashes.

What am I doing wrong? I would be really grateful for any input.

### The code

```
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IdGenerators;
using MongoDB.Driver;

public class Program
{
    static MongoClient client;
    static IMongoDatabase database;
    static IMongoCollection<ValueBase> values;

    public static void Init()
    {
        client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        database = client.GetDatabase("dbtest");
        values = database.GetCollection<ValueBase>("Values");

        if(! BsonClassMap.IsClassMapRegistered(typeof(ValueBase)) )
        {
            BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<ValueBase>(cm => {
                cm.AutoMap();
                cm.SetDiscriminator("Type");

                cm.MapIdField("Id").SetIgnoreIfDefault(true);
                //cm.IdMemberMap.SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance);
            });
        }

        if (!BsonClassMap.IsClassMapRegistered(typeof(IntValue)))
        {
            BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<IntValue>(cm => {
                cm.AutoMap();
            });
        }

        if (!BsonClassMap.IsClassMapRegistered(typeof(StringValue)))
        {
            BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<StringValue>(cm => {
                cm.AutoMap();
            });
        }
    }

    public static async Task Main()
    {
        Init();

        IntValue intval = new IntValue { Value = 15 };
        StringValue strval = new StringValue { Value = "Hello World!" };

        Console.WriteLine($"Before: {intval.Id}");

        await values.InsertOneAsync(intval);
        await values.InsertOneAsync(strval);

        Console.WriteLine($"After: {intval.Id}");

        FilterDefinition<ValueBase> filter = Builders<ValueBase>.Filter.Eq("_id", intval.Id);
        ValueBase val = await values.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        if(val == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not found??");
        }
        else
        {
            if(val.Type == "int") { 
                int theValue = (val as Value<int>).Get();
                Console.WriteLine($"The value is: {theValue}");
            }
        }
    }   
}

public interface Value<T>
{
    T Get();
}

public abstract class ValueBase
{
    [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(StringObjectIdGenerator))]
    public string Id;
    public abstract string Type { get; }
    public abstract object Value { get; set; }
}

public class IntValue : ValueBase, Value<int>
{
    public override string Type { get => "int"; }
    public override object Value { get; set; }

    public int Get()
    {
        return (int)Value;
    }
}

public class StringValue : ValueBase, Value<string>
{
    public override string Type { get => "string"; }
    public override object Value { get; set; }

    public string Get()
    {
        return Value as string;
    }
}
```

### Additional notes

- I found [this post from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37552435/mongodb-c-sharp-does-not-generate-a-value-for-id-objectid-when-using-stringobje) that seems very similar to my problem, however the suggested answer doesn't work for me.
- Just to be sure, I also tried using vstudio 2019, but the problem remains.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid repetition of setIdGenerator for all the classes in c# mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41890080/how-to-avoid-repetition-of-setidgenerator-for-all-the-classes-in-c-sharp-mongodb)